# change default Cursor in Windows Mobile 5 C#

Tags: c#, windows-mobile-5.0

Is it possible to change the default cursor in Windows Mobile 5? I want to change the Cursor to an .ani file.

How can I use this to change the cursor?

```
Cursor.Current =
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like custom `ani` files [are supported](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxcompact/thread/68d681b6-dd26-4f52-9bc4-cface2624959).